# Stuck at command prompt while Running hadoop mapreduce jobs on windows 8

Tags: hadoop

I have gone through the detailed installation videos of installing hadoop on windows 8 without cygwin or any other like hortonworks , sandbox etc.

**My error is that while all things done succeesfully I am  getting below dilemma**

my command prompt stuck like this --

Note that i have not yet installed eclipse kepler and followed dis video--
[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform]

```
 'C:\hworks>hadoop jar c:\hworks\Recipe.jar Recipe /in /out        

15/07/23 11:23:13 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0
:8032
15/07/23 11:23:16 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1

15/07/23 11:23:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1

15/07/23 11:23:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_14
37627735863_0001

15/07/23 11:23:19 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_14
37627735863_0001

15/07/23 11:23:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://SkyneT:80
88/proxy/application_1437627735863_0001/

15/07/23 11:23:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1437627735863_0001'
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue.

You can try these steps that worked for me:

1. Open the command prompt as Administrator.
2. Delete your c:\tmp directory (a new one will be created automatically)
3. Run \etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd to initialize environment variables.
4. Run \bin\hdfs namenode -format
5. Run \sbin\start-all.cmd

Then try running your process again, and post here if you see any new errors